# How do I create functions in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, function, methods, frameworks, sinatra

I have a Sinatra script, and I have a a common method or set of actions that I use in multiple places and I would like to abstract this out to a method. I am unable to find documentation to help me accomplish this, please does anyone have any ideas?

A typical script looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
 'Hello world!'
end

get '/statement' do
 'Hello world!'
end
```

What will be the syntax if I wanted to create a function called `greetings()` that displays "Hello world" for both `/` and `/statement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `def`? Sinatra uses a DSL, but that doesn't rule out normal Ruby stuff.

```
require 'sinatra'

def greetings()
  'Hello world!'
end

get '/' do
  greetings()
end

get '/statement' do
  greetings()
end
```

Saving that to "test.rb" and running it with `ruby test.rb`, then connecting to the running instance at: `http://localhost:4567` lets me see either handler respond using `greetings()`.

Comment: Just to visually indicate to the OP that those were methods.

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra supports a 'helpers' block: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sinatra-helpers-to-clean-up-your-code/